# Is there any way to read password policies via the WMI RSOP_XXX classes?

Tags: wmi, group-policy

Those all reside in the root\RSOP\Computer namespace. The only class from which I got non-empty results is `RSOP_RegistryPolicySetting`, and that one only gave me settings for Windows Update and System Restore configuration.

I do know there are password policies in our network (age, length etc), but queries on the following classes only gave empty resilts:

```
RSOP_ScriptPolicySetting
RSOP_SecuritySettingNumeric
RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean
RSOP_SecuritySettingString
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be via WMI?

If you're running a domain, Microsoft's Scripting Guys have an article [How Long Until My Password Expires?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx)... but it uses ADSI to read policies from Active Directory, rather than policies on the local machine.